# Sending message to the extracted number

Tags: arduino, gsm

Please someone let me know why this code is not working. I want to extract message sender's number and then forward message to it using AT commands. It extracts the number of sender and stores it in a variable but why won't it send a message to that number?

```
#include <GSM.h>
GSM_SMS sms;

char RcvdMsg[200] = "";
int RcvdCheck = 0;
int RcvdConf = 0;
int index = 0;
int RcvdEnd = 0;
char MsgMob[15];
char MsgTxt[50];
int MsgLength = 0;
char number1[12] = "xxxxxxxxxx";
String number;
char inchar;
char outString[22];

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);

  Serial1.print("ATE0\r");
  Serial1.print("AT\r");
  Serial1.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
  Serial1.print("AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0\r");
  delay(1000);
} 

void loop()
{
  recSms();
}

void recSms() 
{
  if(Serial1.available())
  { 
    char data = Serial1.read();
    if(data == '+'){RcvdCheck = 1;}
    if((data == 'C') && (RcvdCheck == 1)){RcvdCheck = 2;}
    if((data == 'M') && (RcvdCheck == 2)){RcvdCheck = 3;} 
    if((data == 'T') && (RcvdCheck == 3)){RcvdCheck = 4;}
    if(RcvdCheck == 4){RcvdConf = 1; RcvdCheck = 0;}

    if(RcvdConf == 1)
    {
      if(data == '\n'){RcvdEnd++;}
      if(RcvdEnd == 3){RcvdEnd = 0;}
      RcvdMsg[index] = data;
      index++;

      if(RcvdEnd == 2){RcvdConf = 0;MsgLength = index-2;index = 0;}
      if(RcvdConf == 0)
      {
        Serial.print("Mobile Number is: ");
        for(int x = 4;x < 17;x++)
        {
          number+=RcvdMsg[x];
          MsgMob[x-4] = RcvdMsg[x];
        }
        Serial.print(number);
        Serial.println();
        Serial.print("Message Text: ");
        for(int x = 46; x < MsgLength; x++)
        {
          MsgTxt[x-46] = RcvdMsg[x];
          inchar=MsgTxt[x-46];
        }
        Serial.print(inchar);
        Serial.println();

        RcvdCheck = 0;
        RcvdConf = 0;
        index = 0;
        RcvdEnd   = 0;
        MsgMob[15];
        MsgTxt[50];
        MsgLength = 0;

        Serial.flush();
        Serial1.flush();

        if(inchar == '#')
        {
          sendInfo();  
        }

      }
    }
  }
 }

 void sendInfo()
 {  
  Serial1.print("AA");
  delay(1000); //delay of 1
  Serial1.println("AT");
  delay(1000); 
  Serial1.write("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");           //set GSM to text mode
  delay(1000); 
  Serial1.write("AT+CPMS=\"SM\"\r\n");         //Preferred SMS Message Storage
  delay(1000); 

  Serial1.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
  Serial1.print(number1);
  Serial1.print("\"");

  delay(1000);
  Serial1.print("HI"); 
  delay(1000);
  Serial1.write(0x1A);           // sends ctrl+z end of message 
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("sms sent ");
} //end sendInfo()
```

Comment: Try minimising your test case. If the problem is with sending, create a file that just does the sending.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the problem seems to be with these lines:

```
Serial1.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
Serial1.print(number1);
Serial1.print("\"");
```

But if we write the lines written below, program works just fine!

```
Serial1.write("AT+CMGS=\"");
Serial1.print(number);
Serial1.write("\"\r");
```